# we created okta_users, and okta_groups using terraform. but i am unable to get the specific user id, and group id

Tags: for-loop, terraform, okta, listobject

We created okta users, and okta groups using terraform

This is variables.tf
used variable list object for users and groups

```
variable "users" {
  type = list(object
    ({
      first_name   = string
      last_name    = string
      email        = string
      organization = string
      role         = string
      okta_admin   = bool
  }))
}

variable "groups" {
  type = list(object
    ({
      name        = string
      description = string
  }))
}
```

This is terraform.tfvars

```
groups = [
  { name = "dev", description = "This group for Devlopers" },
  { name = "qa", description = "This group for QA" },
  { name = "per", description = "This group for Per" }
]

users = [
  { first_name = "a", last_name = "a", email = "a@gmail.com", role = "Engineer", organization = "organization", okta_admin = true },
  { first_name = "b", last_name = "b", email = "b@gmail.com", role = "Lead", organization = "organization", okta_admin = true },
  { first_name = "c", last_name = "c", email = "c@gmail.com", role = "Devloper", organization = "organization", okta_admin = false },
]
```

this is main.tf

to get the values used for_each

```
resource "okta_group" "groups" {
  for_each    = { for group in var.groups : join("-", [group.name, group.description]) => group }
  name        = each.value.name
  description = each.value.description
}



resource "okta_user" "okta_user_add" {
  for_each = { for user in var.users : join("-", [user.first_name, user.last_name]) => user }

  title        = each.value.role
  email        = each.value.email
  first_name   = each.value.first_name
  last_name    = each.value.last_name
  login        = each.value.email
  organization = each.value.organization
}
```

when we are trying to get id we tried multiple things but it didn't work for us.
unable to get the group id and user id's

```
resource "okta_group_memberships" "okta_member_group" {

  for_each = okta_group.groups
  group_id = each.value.id # I want only select one group
  
  users = users = values(okta_user.okta_user_add)[*].id
}
```

**my question is**

> okta_group_memberships.okta_member_group
> we have multiple groups but we need only one group to add in okta_group_memberships.
> and we also to add specific user. I mention in **tfvars** file. there **users** object we have `okta_admin = true`. we need only those users we need in the okta_member_group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For retrieving all the group id, you could iterate over the `okta_user` resources:

```hcl
resource "okta_group_memberships" "okta_member_group" {
  group_id = each.value.id
  
  # Add all users to each group
  users = values(okta_user.okta_user_add)[*].id
}
```

The problem with your question is that you don't specify anywhere which user belongs to which group, so I've used a [`splat`](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/splat) expression to get all the ids of all the users.

You should create a separate input variable in order to map each user to certain group.

Edit:

```hcl
locals {
   # get DEV group
   dev_group = [for group in var.groups: group if group.name == "dev"][0]
   # filter okta admins
   okta_admins = [for user in var.users: join("-", [user.first_name, user.last_name]) if user.okta_admin]
}


resource "okta_group_memberships" "okta_member_group" {

  # select only the DEV group
  group_id = okta_group.groups[join("-", [local.dev_group.name, local.dev_group.description])].id
  
  # get IDs of okta_admins only
  users = [for okta_admin in local.okta_admins: okta_user.okta_user_add[okta_admin].id]
}
```

Comment: Corrected, it should be `users = values(okta_user.okta_user_add)[*].id`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
As i shown in the question. there i given **terraform.tfvars** file. in that we have two different object. one is groups and another users. 
in users we inserted `okta_admin = true`. 
we need only those true value those users only we need in the membersip groups

Comment: I suggest asking a new question and avoiding to modify this. Neither I or anyone get notified about your changes on your question. There are other people as well who can help you out with your issues.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions. I will follow it.
please suggest a suitable answer to my questions.

Comment: I'm sorry, at this point is unclear for me what do you mean by "I want only select one group". Which group do you want?

Comment: in groups I need **dev** group and from users **okta_admin = true** those users only

Comment: I've edited my answer. I'm not entirely sure if it will work, it is nearly impossible for me to reproduce your environment. I hope it helps.

Comment: it's working for users. 
for group_id its not working.

Comment: ` Error: Invalid index
│
│   on main.tf line 42, in resource "okta_group_memberships" "devops_group_member":
│   42:   group_id = okta_group.groups[join("-", [var.groups["dev"].name, var.groups["dev"].description])].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.groups is a list of object, known only after apply
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value: a number is required. `

Comment: Yeah... you have to write a filter for the dev list as well. I updated my answer...again

Comment: Thanks @ervin-szilagyi for valuable time. it's working.